# Calculate limsup of $\frac{1}{n^{p/n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to find-

> $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\Big|\frac{1}{n^{p/n}}\Big|$ where $p\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I am not sure how to calculate that. All I have proved is that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If a sequence is convergent the its $\lim \sup$ is same as its limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do I know if the sequence given here is convergent?

Comment: @Harmonic My answer below shows how sequence converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1$ then for $p \in \mathbb Z$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{p/n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n^{1/n})^{-p} = \big(\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n}\big)^{-p} = 1^{-p} = 1
$$ So, the sequence $(1/n^{p/n})_{n = 1}^\infty$ converges to $1$ and so the $\limsup$ must also be this same value.

Comment: How do you know limit can be taken inside exponent?

Comment: @Harmonic The function $f(x) = x^{-p}$ is continuous for all $p \in \mathbb Z$ and all $x > 0$ . This allows the exchange of exponents.